# Is there a Django plugin for Pycharm/Intellij?

Tags: python, django, web

I am working on a blog in django.So is there any Plugin for Pycharm or Intellij idea for django like VS code has?

Comment: The paid version of PyCharm has support for Django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I probably think it is a pro feature.
If you are a student, then use your .edu mail account to get PyCharm Professional for free.